# Runnable running every 20 seconds instead of the specified delay

Tags: java, android

The idea is for my runnable to run every minute.

Instead, it runs in roughly about 20 seconds and I have no idea why.

Below is the code:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //Post from Queue & update post
                if (NetworkUtils.isConnected()) {

                    //post from queue
                    try {
                        postHelper.postFromQueue();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Update posts
                    postHelper.updateSolicitations();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            finally{
                //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
                handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
            }
        }
    };
```

I don't know if it's relevant but it's onCreate method of MainActivity.

Comment: your code is OK. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay

Comment: remove calbacks from handler in onPause/onStop

Comment: @dit that is a much better way to do it and it works smoothly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you consider using ScheduledExecutorService

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService execService
                    =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
        //The repetitive task, say to update Database
        System.out.println("hi there at: "+ new java.util.Date());
    }, Delay, Rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );//TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS is time unit
}
```

Comment: I replace TimeUnit.MILISECONDS with the amount of time I need? Is it async?

Comment: in android we are using Handler.

Comment: @Rosenberg You replace Delay with time you want to delay before this task runs, Rate is the time for repeat ex:
execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
        //The repetitive task, say to update Database
    }, 0, 6000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
this will repeat every 6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use a scheduled where you define a quartz cronjob that is then triggered whenever you defined it.

you can do something like every minute or second or every day at 3 o'clock

[Simple Quartz/Cron job setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912941/simple-quartz-cron-job-setup)

Comment: This isn't an option in android

Comment: true is think I accidentally skipped the fact that we are talking about Android

Answer (score -4):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {                                    

 try{
                //Post from Queue & update post
                if (NetworkUtils.isConnected()) {

                    //post from queue
                    try {
                        postHelper.postFromQueue();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Update posts
                    postHelper.updateSolicitations();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }



    }
}, 60000);
```